# Проблема с чтением бинарных данных

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Возникла проблема при чтении бинарных данных( *.wav файл ) из stdin.
При чтении массива данных размером 65536(запись производится ровно такого размера), корректно читается только 4412 байт, после чтение прерывается так как приходит символ eof. Следовательно отсюда вопрос: каким образом это можно обойти ?

Cборка идёт под ОС WIN 10 x64
компилятор: msvc13

Привожу краткий код чтения и записи:

```
    std::array<char, SoundVector::Buffer::size> buf
    std::vector<char> input;

    std::memset(buf.data(), 0x00, buf.size());

    std::ifstream is(stdin);
    is.setf(std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);

    size_t ssize = is.read(buf.data(),buf.size()).gcount();
```

Запись:

```
std::ofstream of(stdout);
of.setf(std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);

std::array<char, SoundVector::Buffer::size> buf;
std::memset(buf.data(), 0x0, buf.size());
std::memcpy(buf.data() + offset, vectorSound.data(), sizeData);
of.write(buf.data(), buf.size());


vectorSound представляет из себя std::vector<short> c данными
```

P.S. Если записывать буффер, всебайты которого заполнены 0xff, то всё проходит хорошо.

Comment: а зачем вам читать из stdin? Почему не читаете просто из файла?

Comment: У файловых потоков нет конструктора, принимающего на вход `FILE*`, вы нигде не проверяете, открываются, записывают / читают или нет. Поток, читающий из `stdin` называется `cin`, пишущий в `stdout` - `cout`.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, потому как нужно Pipe организовать.

Comment: если повторно вызвать read(если вы прочитали меньше, чем нужно), количество прочитанных байтов будет равно ноль? Файл будет считаться достигнутым конца?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, да всё верно ! Так и будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось на уровне функций ОС.
Необходимо использовать конструкцию вида:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) == -1){
        sMode = false;
    }
#else
    if (setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY) == -1){
        sMode = false;
    }
#endif
```

для чтения бинарного ввода данных.

Полный пример кода :

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) == -1){
        sMode = false;
    }
#else
    if (setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY) == -1){
        sMode = false;
    }
#endif

if ( !sMode ){
    throw std::runtime_error("*** ERROR *** Can not set binary mode read ");
}

std::array<uint8_t, sound::size> buf;
std::ifstream in(stdin);
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size());
in.close();
```